# How to generate random choices for random.choice() function using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am trying to create a function which generates a random password using random.choice function,but i also want the choices to be random,i am trying to use a dict for this purpose,but not getting the desired result..
My code is:

```
def makepassword():
    letter1=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    letter2=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    symbol1=["@","#","$","%","&","*","<",">"]
    symbol2=["@","#","$","%","&","*","<",">"]
    number1=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    dict1={0:"letter1",1:"letter2",2:"symbol1",3:"symbol2",4:"number1"}
    k=dict1.get(randint(0,4))
    l=dict1.get(randint(0,4))
    m=dict1.get(randint(0,4))
    print(k,l,m)
    password=(choice(k)+choice(l)+choice(m))
    print(password)
```

If i print and check the values of `k,l,m`
am getting values such as `letter1/letter2/symbol1/symbol2/number1` so trying to use those values in choice function.

where as when i directly use: `password=(choice(letter1)+choice(symbol1)+choice(number1))` it works fine.

So how the above Choice function can be implemented using Dictionary.

Comment: Well, you can simply remove the quotes around the values of the dictionary, but I don't think this'll bring more randomness. You could just concatenate these lists and make random choices from the concatenated version.

Comment: "I am trying to create a function which generates a random password using random.choice function,but i also want the choices to be random" - what, were you under the impression that `random.choice` always made the same choice? It's not called `deterministic.choice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1={0:letter1,1:letter2,2:symbol1,3:symbol2,4:number1}
```

You want to store the actual list in the dictionary, instead of the name of the lists. This will allow you to do what you want to do; to use the lists when you access the dictionary.

Note that `random`'s module warns about using it for security:

> Warning The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the secrets module.

It recommends [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module. It also has a [`choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice) method too.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach (working example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/GbVn/1)):

`weights` specifies how many of each type is required. The rest are randomly chosen.

`length` is the total length of the resulting password

```
from random import randint, choice, shuffle
import string

def makepassword(length=8, weights=[1,1,1,1]):
    password_builder= []
    for index, weight in enumerate(weights):
      for _ in range(weight):
        password_builder.append(index)
    while len(password_builder) < length:
      password_builder.append(randint(0, len(weights) - 1))
    shuffle(password_builder)
    lowercase=string.ascii_lowercase
    uppercase=string.ascii_uppercase
    symbols=["@","#","$","%","&","*","<",">"]
    numbers=string.digits
    types=[lowercase,uppercase,symbols,numbers]
    print(password_builder)

    password = []

    for char_type in password_builder:
      password.append(choice(types[char_type]))

    print(''.join(password))

makepassword()
```

Examples:

```
re9Bf6s#
qV7GCn0#
51zt7N>Z
&u7sYQ&0
5ZOF@m&u
```

Comment: Upvote for adding weights and also using the string module

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `dict`, also use the [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module:

```
import random
import string

symbols = ("@","#","$","%","&","*","<",">")
choices = (
    string.ascii_lowercase,
    string.ascii_uppercase,
    symbols,
    symbols,
    string.digits
)

def make_password(length):
    return ''.join(
        map(
            str,
            (
                random.choice(random.choice(choices))
                for _ in xrange(length)
            )
        )
    )

print(make_password(4))
print(make_password(10))
print(make_password(6))
```

#### Output:

```
J&@0
g8*o3$I4O*
@#$FQ<
```